# Read audio Markers/Regions in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, audio

Premiere CC 2014 is unable to read marker data in a wave file.

I'm migrating from Vegas Pro, and this program is able to read markers from the start.

**Vegas Pro**:

[image]

**Premiere Pro**:

[image]

Is there a way to make Premiere read marker/region data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Audition can read BWF markers but Premiere [doesn't](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4007712#4007712). So, two options are

1) to save separately the regions between [markers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0s4t3QrZmHY).

or

2) export a WAV from Audition, with cue points that which Premiere seems to [see](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/3/963460).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to open an audio with metadata in Audition and save it with "include markers and other metadata" and Premiere was able to read all the markers.